# Java increase the array size

Tags: java

I have the following code that takes integers and stores it in a array of booleans according to the position. I have a method include that allows the user to input more numbers into the array however if the number is bigger than the array size then I need to increase the size. I am aware that you can't do much with arrays once they are made just change what's in each position. Is there a quick way to make it bigger or could I use arraylists to keep the array size changing?

```
public class ISet {
    public int max;
    boolean[] numArray;


    ISet(int a) {
        this.size = a;
        this.numArray = new boolean[size];

    }

    public void include(int n) {
        if (n > size) {
            this.size = n;
            numArray[n]=true;

        }
        else

            numArray[n]=true;


        }
```

Comment: Arrays once allocated memory cannot be resized. This requires to create a new array of the desired size and copy the contents of the original array to the newly created array, probably using `java.lang.System.arraycopy(...);`

Comment: For what purpose is this? Instead of storing "true" at index "number", consider storing "number" in a list/set/map and if a list contains a "number" that "number" is true, if not, false.

Comment: Take a look here; http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/ to see which collection suits you the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either simply use an ArrayList, although it'll have to be `ArrayList<Boolean>` as opposed to boolean (the primitive data type). Probably the easiest solution.

The other option would be to create a new, larger array and copy every element from the current array to the new one when the size of the current array is exceeded.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make it bigger yourself you can use `Arrays.copyOf(numArray, newLength)` which will copy your array into a new new array of the specified length adding falses at the end if the new length is longer than the original.

Otherwise you can use an ArrayList.

Answer (score 1):

You should use an ArrayList.

Normal arrays have a fixed size in Java.

Comment: I thought I might have to. Can I use a set of booleans or is that something from python?

Comment: A Java Set would not be appropriate in this situation as its purpose is to contain unique elements.

Answer (score 0):

For "normal" code you should use `ArrayList` instead.

For application that use extreme huge arrays, the array needs much less memory, than the ArrayList, because an Object needs 4 at least 4 times (16 bytes) more memory than a primitive.

For such special situations, you can use `Arrays.copyOf()` which copies the content into a new bigger array.
See also src cocde of `ArrayList.java`